Rear wheel resistance but moves freely when not biking?
Hi all I'm at a bit of loss trying to trouble shoot my Surly Long Haul Trucker.I recently bought it used about 3 months ago and then had a new chain and cassette installed.
Commuting back from work yesterday and the rear wheel suddenly is not turning properly with a lot of resistance. When I flipped it over to check for anything caught it all looks clear, brakes are okay, moving the pedals spins the rear wheel with no issue.
I'm guessing this is a hub or bearing problem in the rear wheel. Tried greasing the hub in the hope that it might help but so far it hasn't. Should I try more grease? Something else?

Take the wheel off of the bicycle.
Now, with the orientation the same as when mounted, use your right hand to spin the cassette backwards.
Does it spin freely? yes? Spin the axle. does it spin freely?
Look at the inside of the frame dropout next to the cluster and above the derailleur, any scrapes from the gear cluster rubbing the frame?
Answer those questions and you'll get answers.

Please don't slap grease on - it might cure the symptom not the cause.
Are you able to add some photos with [edit] ?  We might be able to see something.

My top guess is Broken Axle.
